# Counter speed increases when the start button is clicked again

Tags: javascript

When the *start* button is clicked once, everything works perfectly fine. However, when the *start* button is clicked multiple times (by accident for example), the speed of the counter increases and the *stop* button doesn't seem to work any more!

Why is this happening? And what can I do to prevent the *start* button (if clicked accidentally) from increasing the speed of the timer when it is already running?

```html
<button id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
    <button id="stopBtn" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
    <h2 id="timer"></h2>
    <script>
        let myCounter
        function startTimer() {
            myCounter = setInterval(counter, 200);
        }
        function stopTimer() {
            clearInterval(myCounter);
        }
        let i = 0;
        function counter() {
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i++;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You're setting another interval on every click. Just check if `myCounter` is holding a value first and set `myCounter = null` after clearing it in `stopTimer`.

Comment: That click creates another interval, copy the line `clearInterval(myCounter)` also as the first line into `startTimer` function.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. That works to some extent, but still each time you click on the *start* button again it pauses the timer for 200 milliseconds. When you keep clicking on the *start* button again and again, it even pauses the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your question, it's unclear if you want the timer to reset if the user clicks the start button again, however with my answer, I came to the conclusion that you didn't.

Here's a modified version of `startTimer()` which utilizes a **guard clause** to check if an interval already exists (and if so, don't start again)

```
function startTimer() {

    // Guard clause! If the counter exists, exit the function!
    if(myCounter) {
        return
    }

    myCounter = setInterval(counter, 200);
}
```

A tiny update of the stop function is also needed to `set myCounter` to `null` after the counter is stopped:

```
function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(myCounter);
    // Set the counter to Null, because it is still declared even though it has no value! (try removing this line and see what happens when you hit start again)
    myCounter = null;
}
```

Comment: No I don't want the timer to reset if they user clicks the *start* button again. You got what I meant correctly, and thank you very much. Your help was really useful. This was something I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable that can helps you detect if the counter is already clicked or not, with the condition of that variable, you can have what you want, I edited your code.

```html
<button id="startBtn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
    <button id="stopBtn" onclick="stopTimer()">Stop</button>
    <h2 id="timer"></h2>
    <script>
        let myCounter
        let clicked = false;
        function startTimer() {
            if(!clicked){
                myCounter = setInterval(counter, 200);
            }
            clicked = true;
        }
        function stopTimer() {
            if(clicked){
              clearInterval(myCounter);
            }
            clicked = false;
        }
        let i = 0;
        function counter() {
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i++;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: just check if `myCounter` is holding a value and set it to `null` in stopTimer, avoids needing another variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was really helpful, too. I hadn't thought about this from this angle. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply disable the start button once clicked, and re-enable it when the stop button is clicked.

```js
let i = 0;
let myCounter;

let startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
let stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
let timer = document.getElementById('timer');

function startTimer() {
  startBtn.disabled = true;
  stopBtn.disabled = false;
  myCounter = setInterval(counter, 200);
}

function stopTimer() {
  startBtn.disabled = false;
  stopBtn.disabled = true;
  clearInterval(myCounter);
}

function counter() {
  i++; timer.value = i;
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
stopBtn.addEventListener('click', stopTimer);
```

```html
<button id="startBtn">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn" disabled>Stop</button>
<h2><output id="timer">0</output></h2>
```

As an added measure, you can even hide the disabled button so only the active one is shown.

```css
button:disabled {
  display: none;
}
```